# CSS not loading from App_Themes

Tags: asp.net, css

I am having problem while loading the `CSS` file through `App_Themes folder`, I am setting the theme of the page dynamically using code behind by `OnPreInit` Event and every thing  goes fine ie the skin loads perfectly but the corresponding CSS to that specific theme is not loading any help from you will be very much appreciated.

Note: I am loading pages to `Iframe`.

Comment: Are you dynamically changing the theme by `OnPreInit` in the pages which are being loaded into the `Iframe` or just the page which holds the `Iframe`?

Comment: Both i tried but i was in-vain

Comment: Can you verify whether the <link> elements are actually present in the HTML, and maybe the request is failing?  Check FireBug (in FireFox) Net panel to see if the request is there, but failing too...

Comment: I have already checked it Brian and  link element is missing. I dont know weather this problem is because of  Iframe?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to allow anonymous access to your theme in your web.config file, particularly if you are using Visual Studio's Development Server instead of IIS.

```
<location path="App_Themes/YourThemeFolder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Web.config

```
<pages styleSheetTheme="YourThemeName"> 
</pages>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me and give +1 -- Thank You!!!.  I just now upgraded webforms asp-app from VS2012 (4.6.1) to VS2017 (4.6.1) by starting with a "default VB web-app" project.  This created a whole new web.config.  I then added the "code" into the default structure in the file-system and included my original code-files into the project.  After wrestling with newer Ajax and ReportViewer the project compiled, but the display was wrong -- not finding the previous App-Theme contents.under the themes and skins and CSS.  This simple one-line addition FIXED the app.  Thanks...John

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps anyone, but I faced problem after upgrading my .NET from 3.5 to 4.5.1. After the upgrade, the style is missing for certain pages and I noticed that the CSS files from the App_Themes folder is not loading. The difference between the pages that are working and the pages that are not working is that the pages that are working contains the Theme="Default" attribute at the top of the aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Theme="Default" ...
```